# What is the most downvoted question on MathStackExchange or Math Meta?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, voting, meta

I saw this post on MSE, which I thought was pretty funny. Then, I realized the ridiculous amount of downvotes it got within an hour. So, that made me think, what is the most downvoted question in history on MSE or math meta? I am aware of the duplicate question, but it doesn't show any good solutions to find any DELETED posts, and I would like to know what the most downvoted question was of all time, which includes the time before the question was deleted.

### Heading

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I am aware of the duplicate question...." I'm not. Link?

Comment: Ok I laughed at the question tho lol

Comment: *What is the most downvored question* No offence ,but what good does it do by knowing that ?There are several ways to waste one's time

Comment: Go to data.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by *most downvoted* - whether you mean the lowest score or the most downvotes.

For the lowest score you can simply [choose the votes tab](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes) and then go to the end of the list. However, you can also create a [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) query [for questions with the lowest score](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1371981/questions-with-the-lowest-score). Using SEDE has the advantage that the data contains also the deleted questions, so you can get a [query including the deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1371985/questions-with-the-lowest-score-including-the-deleted-ones).

If you want the number of downvotes (rather than score - which also takes into account the number of upvotes), you can use the Votes table. For example, you can get a [query like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1371987/questions-with-the-most-downvotes). (The queries I have included here can be improved and modified in various ways. And, of course, you can run them on various sites - the links I provided use Mathematics Meta.)

Comment: lol the most downvoted here in meta isn't remotely surprising. The most negative question on the main site is certainly something though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing these quarries, I think that I learned a lot about the MSE culture and people's opinions by reading the most donw-voted questions and the answers to them.